# How to split items in a list to create a string with characters in between?

Tags: python, prime-factoring

i wrote a code to print a list of a number's prime factorization, and for example, if the user input was "18", it would output "[2, 3, 3]". how do i make it print in such a way that it follows this format: "18 = 2x3x3"?

Comment: Provide your code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
l = [2,3,3]
number = 18

def printList(number, l):
    print(str(number) +" = " + "x".join(str(i) for i in l))

printList(number, l)
```

Result:

```
18 = 2x3x3
```

Although I don't think that is that much of a challenge to write a piece of code that does this job.